# Trying to add a percentage of a variable to itself in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a variable that is an `Int` (`loan`). I want to add 10% to it each time a button is clicked.

I've tried various methods, firstly:

```
loan = 50
loan = loan + loan / 100 * 10
```

when I print `loan`, it still shows 50 without the 10 percent added.

Next, I tried declaring a new `Int` variable (`percent`) to work out the percentage:

```
loan = 50
var percent = loan / 100 * 10
loan = loan + percent
```

Again, `loan` prints 50 and `percent` prints 0.

In each case, I've experimented putting the maths into brackets, but that gives the same result. I'm sure this must be a very simple fix but I can't work it out, and have had no luck googling.

Comment: Use a `Double`, otherwise `loan / 100` truncates to zero ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add 10% to it each time a button is clicked.

You can either add 10%, or a tenth, of the original value, or multiply by 1.1:

```
var loan = 50.0       // including the decimal point makes it a float
```

...any of these will work:

```
loan = loan + loan * 0.1
loan = loan * 1.1
loan += loan * 0.1
loan *= 1.1
```

> Again, "loan" prints 50 and "percent" prints 0.

That's because `loan` was declared as an integer type, and the other values in your calculation were also integers, so the compiler inferred that `percent` should also be an integer. You could fix that by explicitly setting the type of either `loan` or `percent` to `Float` or `Double`, like this:

```
var percent : Float = loan / 10
```

Or you can do it implicitly, as I did up top, by setting `loan` to `50.0` instead of `50`. The compiler will understand that `50.0` is a `Float`, so it'll infer that `loan` is a `Float`, which would then cause calculations done with `loan` to be of that type, and `percent` would also be a `Float`.

Comment: It would help to explain why this answer works while theirs doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `loan` is declared as an `Int`. `Int`s cannot have fractional components, so when you try to divide 50 by 100, the answer, 0.5, has its fractional component stripped off, making 0. Times that by 10, and it's still zero, so when you add it to `loan`, it doesn't change the result.

You can solve this by declaring `loan` as a `Double` instead of an `Int`. You can also just multiply by 1.1 to add 10%.

```
var loan: Double = 50

loan *= 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

first, loan should be double (cause int cannot have fractions)

Then you can do something like this:

```
loan = 50
loan *= 1.1
```

Comment: It's not the nearest integer, but the floor.. so 50/51 = 0

Comment: @KaiHuppmann It's technically not the floor, though, because of the possibility of an `Int` being negative. `floor(-0.5)` is -1.0, whereas `(-1 as Int) / 2` is 0. It's probably better just to say that it's the integer component of the value rather than the floor.